# Why are all strings getting reversed?

Tags: masm, masm32, microprocessors

Following is the question that I had in my test today-

Write an ALP that will examine a set of strings. The length each string is four characters. The number of strings to be examined is stored in location ‘cnt1’. The count will not exceed 20d . The strings are stored starting from location ‘dat1’. The ALP should scan each string and see if it is equal to ‘ ‘ (four blank spaces). If yes, all strings that follow this string of four blank spaces should be reversed until the next string of four blank spaces is encountered. You can assume that there will not be more than 2 blank strings in the array.
For e.g. if the set of strings are
‘math’, ‘have’, ‘ ‘, ‘bury’, ‘mine’, ‘dine’, ‘ ‘ , ‘hell’, ‘deep’, ‘tree’
The ALP should change it to
‘math’, ‘have’, ‘ ‘, ‘yrub’, ‘enim’, ‘enid’ , ‘ ‘ , ‘hell’, ‘deep’, ‘tree’
You have to use a single instruction to reverse the string.

I wrote an ALP code and ran it using MASM but all the strings were getting reversed instead of few.
Following is my code-

.

```
model tiny
.486
.data
dat1 dd 'math','have','    ','bury','mine','dine','    ','hell','deep','tree'
cnt1 db 10
.code
.startup
    lea si,dat1
    mov di,si
    mov cl,cnt1       
    mov ch,0                     
    cld         
x1: lodsd
    mov ebx,20202020h
    cmp eax,ebx
    jnz x2
    inc ch
x5: cmp ch,2h
    jz x3                        
    cmp ebx,dword ptr[si]
    jz x3
    bswap eax 
    add si,4
    add di,4
    dec cl
    jnz x5
    jmp x3                       
x2: add si,4
    add di,4
    dec cl
    jnz x1 
x3:
.exit
end
```

But instead of only few strings getting reversed all of them are getting reversed. Please help me debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd 'math'` causes `'math'` to be treated as a 32-bit integer where `'m'` is the most significant byte, and `'h'` is the least significant (i.e. just as if you had written `dd 6874616Dh`).

If you want the bytes to be written out with the left-most one first you can just replace `dd` with `db`. The other option would be to write the strings backwards (i.e. `'htam'`, etc).

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!